# Oracle Apex Additional Forms

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working to achieve a flexible form region where a user can add additional forms. My tables are users and wallets, a user can have many wallets. The end goal is to allow a user to add as many wallets they would like in one page, to do this I will need to add Dynamic Forms. Normally in the MEAN stack, It is common for us to loop the form, so if a user clicks on a button it will generate a form and send the JSON Request as an array. I don't know how to get this done as I am a beginner in **Oracle Apex**

Comment: you can do this using a master detail interactive grid. Look at this example. One department can have many employees. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=150297:35:

Comment: Gratitude as I've customized this and it is working fine.